# how return bool from validate a variable without use if?

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, methods, boolean

I have the next method:

```
    public boolean validarexist(String var){
        if (var.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }        
    }
```

I how there is a method to do it in one line. some like:

```
 public boolean validarexist(String var){
      return XXXXXXX(var); // in one line you can validate it
 }
```

do you know and alternative to do this kind of validation?

Comment: you mean ``!var.isEmpty()``?

Comment: no. some that go return you false if var is empty and true if var have somthing

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: Your current method returns false if var is empty and true if var has something, so `!var.isEmpty()` will give the same result

Comment: use less code lines. !var.isEmpty() this do it ? @Ecto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it simply as

```
public boolean validarexist(String var){
    return !var.isEmpty();
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. When `var.isEmpty()` is `true`, `!true` = `false` i.e. `false` will be returned.
2. When `var.isEmpty()` is `false`, `!false` = `true` i.e. `true` will be returned.